# How do I change the content of a div when a colorbox form has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok heres my problem, I have a single page app which has a dashboard and popup forms, the dashboard contains (amongst other things) a list of invoices with totals. i can edit one of these invoices by clicking a button. this loads the editor in a colorbox. If i edit the invoice i need to not only update the row in question but need to update the totals area and change the total for this invoice in the list on the dashboard. So I've 2 problems here:

1. how can i update the totals in the colorbox?
2. how can i update the invoice total in the dashboard?

So lets use an example, I click the button for invoice-1 which currently totals 190 and the popup loads. I add a row which has a cost of 20, my totals (total on the colorbox form) are now out by 20 and the div called total-1 (the total for invoice-1) is also out by this amount.

I tried a few things yesterday but in the end i got around the first issue by reloading the colorbox form by adding a reload button. this then gets the values updated but is far from ideal (page jumping etc)

I still need to update the total in the dashboard (visible in the dom without colorbox) I have the value in the colorbox and the id of the invoice total at hand is 'total-1') so I thought ok so i can update the total-1 value when the colorbox form has loaded and use a script tag to do this.

```
<script>
    $("div #total-1").text("210"); // 210 is dynamically calculated (190 + 20)
</script>
```

this however doesn't work despite the element already existing in the dom when the colorbox loads it's content. I also tried $(document).ready() and $(window).loaded() (plus variants on these).

I'm thinking perhaps I'm barking up the wrong tree here. Theres a few issues here, how can i avoid reloading the colorbox form but have the totals of the tables add and show the result. Secondly how can i ensure the value of total-1 is updated without reloading the page.

thanks

Comment: try  $("#total-1").html("210");

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully Grumpy is right. Try it

```
  <script>
       $("div #total-1").html("210");
  </script>
```